# "GET" request dateformat problem in .net core web Api 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I have .net core 2.1 Web Api project. And I'm sending `GET` request like below. I'm sending "10.12.2019" by postman. But I'm getting from controller as "12.10.2019". There was this issue in `POST` request. I fixed by adding below code to `Startup.cs`.But, problem continueing in `GET` request. How can I fix for `GET` request?

**MyController.cs**

```
[HttpGet]
public void MyGetMethod(DateTime myDate)
{ }
```

**My Url**

```
http://localhost:5012/api/MyController/MyGetMethod?myDate=10.12.2019
```

**My Startup.cs**

```
   services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
   {
       options.SerializerSettings.Culture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");
   });

///////////////////////////////
   var defaultCulture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");
   app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
   {
       DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(defaultCulture),
       SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { defaultCulture },
       SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> { defaultCulture }
   });
```

Comment: Not that it is a solution to this particular issue per se, but I would accept a string as input and then make a `DateTime.TryParse` with that string input from the GET-request. More like a work-around, but would be my advice. This would allow you to target the exact formatting you'd like.

Comment: I don't want taking as string. Because, in that case, I must do datetime parsing in everywehere. So, I want to fix my localization. But, I didn't understand the reason of this bug. @jwweiler

Answer (score 0):

ok I can see one solution for this problem. You pass it into the body (as data) and pass the format with it. For example

> new Date().toUTCString()

and on the server you can receive it like

```
public void MyGetMethod([FromBody] DateTime myDate)
```

Comment: Yes. It maybe solve this issue @Gaurav. But, I don't want changing my parameters. I want to solve issue from C# side.

Comment: Then you need to use custom model binder for date time. Using this link for details http://www.vickram.me/custom-datetime-model-binding-in-asp-net-web-api

Comment: That link for asp.net. But, I'm using asp.net Core. So, I couldn't use it.